# Why does my custom VM Image not show up in Azure Create VM Interface?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I recently went through the hassle of creating and uploading a .VHD image containing a nice little Debian installation to my Azure Storage Account. It was created in Fixed Mode and uploaded as a PageBlob.

After a couple of attempts I was able to create an Image from my Blob, but I have no idea where to go from here.

Obviously, I want to create a VM instance from my image, but I can't figure out how to select my Image. I followed the `NEW > Compute > Virtual Machine > From Gallery` link, and there is a tab labeled `My Images`, but my image does not show up there.

Does anyone have an idea why?

EDIT: When I try to create a Disk from my Blob, I get the following Error:

> The storage account does not support this operation. Please check the location of this storage account or create a new storage account and retry.

But the Disk is not associated with any storage account, or is it?

Comment: The only VM's I've seen in "My Images" are images that I've created using the Azure portal interface. Does your VHD show up under "My Disks"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've uploaded your VHD you should be able to create a new disk using `Virtual Machines > Disks > Create Disk` this will prompt you for the url of the VHD you uploaded and allow you to specify the OS type and a name for the disk.

From there you can create a new Virtual Machine. `New > Compute > Virtual Machine > From Gallery > My Disks`

**EDIT**
I'm told by a colleague that some storage accounts do not support disks for VM's and a workaround can be to create a new VM using the portal (either from scratch or using a pre-made gallery image) this will create a storage account called something like portalvhdxxxxxxxx. You should then be able to upload your VHD to this storage account and create your disk from there.

Comment: Hi, when I try to create a Disk from my Blob it sais: `The storage account does not support this operation. Please check the location of this storage account or create a new storage account and retry.` Do you know what that means? I'll quickly edit my question to reflect this new aspect.

Comment: Is the Storage account in the same Location (West Europe, East Asia etc) as the one the disk is being created in?

Comment: Apparently some storage accounts don't support VM disks, edited answer with another suggestion.

Comment: okay, I've re-uploaded the .vhd to the predefined storage account, and was able to create a disk from that, and was also able to create a vm from that disk. thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: I have a storage account created that has name like portalvhdxxxxxx. But when I try to create a disk out of that VHD I get "A lease conflict occurred with the blob https...." error. Can someone please help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and this question helped me get around it. To provide more details, Azure VMs are not currently supported in certain data centers (such as North Central US). So if you create a storage account in an unsupported data center, you'll be able to upload vhd blobs and even create an image from it via the Azure portal. However that image will not show up under My Images when you attempt to spin up a VM from it.

It's pretty confusing but that seems to be what is happening. So if you want to store your vhd blobs in a storage account that isn't called portalvhdxxxxxx, just make sure your storage account is created in a data center that supports VMs. To figure out exactly what those data centers are, they are the data centers that you can choose when you quick create a VM directly on the portal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where I was unable to find the image in "Shared Images". However, I've learnt that the subscription under which I was trying to create the VM is different from the Subscription in which the Shared Image is present.

After, I have selected **"Default Subscription filter"**  in portal settings to **'Select All'**, I was able to see the image in "Shared Images".

**Note:** Though it is a Shared Image, the Default Subscription should be set to 'Select All' when you are creating VMs across different subscriptions.